Prove the Linear Transformation in Different Basis $B = P^{-1}AP$
In a linaer transformation $T: V\to V$, A is the representatioin matrix of basis E, B is the representatioin matrix of basis F, $F = EP$ , then $B = P^{-1}AP$. Idk how to prove it.
Attempt:
suppose $E \overset{T}\to E', F \overset{T}\to F', x \overset{T}\to x', y \overset{T}\to y'$, x, y,x',y' are the coordinate in respective basis.
Then $E'x' = F'y'\to EAx' = FBy'\to Ax' = PBy'$
If $B = P^{-1}AP$, $x' = Py'$, but I only know $x = Py$
Question:

How to derieve $x' = Py'$?


I'll explain a little bit about how bases work for clarification, and then I will answer the question.
If $x$ is an element of V, then you can write it as $$x= a_1\beta_1+\dots+ a_n\beta_n $$ where the $a_i$ are scalars and the $\beta_i$ elements of V. So in this basis (let's call it $\beta$) we get the coordinate vector
$$ x_\beta = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots\\ a_n\end{pmatrix}$$
Note that we can  calculate $T(\beta_i)$ for each $i$ and express this in the basis $\beta$ again, then there are some $c_{j,i}$ such that $$T(\beta_i)= c_{1,i}\beta_1+\dots+c_{n,i}\beta_n $$
So we can write it's coordinate vector as $$ T(\beta_i)_{\beta} = \begin{pmatrix} c_{1,i} \\ \vdots\\ c_{n,i}\end{pmatrix}$$
This vectors are just the column vectors of the matrix representation of $T$ in the basis $\beta$, let's call it $A$. So $A$ is:
$$ A= \begin{pmatrix} c_{1,1} & \dots & c_{1,n}  \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ c_{n,1}& \dots & c_{n,n} \end{pmatrix}$$
Now if $\beta'$ is another basis there exists a change-of-basis matrix $P$ between $\beta'$ and $\beta$ such that $Px_{\beta'}= x_\beta$. This matrix $P$ must be invertible since a chance of basis is just an automorphism.
Now let's answer your question.  We want to know what the coordinate vector of $T(x)$ in the basis $\beta'$ is. Note that
\begin{align}
T(x)_{\beta}  &= Ax_\beta\\
Bx_{\beta'}=T(x)_{\beta'} &= P^{-1}Ax_\beta\\
              &= P^{-1}A Px_{\beta'}
\end{align}
Since the matrix representation $B$ in $\beta'$ is unique and $x$ is arbitrary  then $B= P^{-1}A P$.
